# How to add and remove property from Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a initialState:

```
let initialState = {
   items: []
}
```

and i have a payload from my action like that eg:

```
{name: 'A', age: 2}, {name: 'B', age: 1}
```

after setting my payload to my reducer:

```
case SET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
     items: [...state.items, ...action.payload],
      };
```

after that my state is:

```
 let initialState = {
       items: [
          {name: 'A', age: 2}, 
          {name: 'B', age: 1}
       ],
    }
```

so I want to add to each item in items eg one more property like that:

```
 let initialState = {
           items: [
              {name: 'A', age: 2, active: true}, 
              {name: 'B', age: 1, active: true}
           ],
        }
```

how i can do that?

Comment: Why don't you just add the property when dispatching the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` fro this:

```
case SET_ITEMS:
  return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        active: true
      }))
    };
```

Comment: Line 202:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: @user3348410 sorry, my bad, there was an extra parenthesis missing, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update both payload and state to add extra property you can also do this.

```
case SET_ITEMS:
  return {
    ...state,
 items: [
...state.items.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        active: true
      })),
 ...action.payload.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        active: true
      }))
],
  };
```